# Outlook Add-in REST API In Shared Inbox Fails: ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId - Item Id doesn't belong to the current mailbox

Tags: outlook, office-js, add-in, outlook-web-addins

We have an Outlook (Office JS) Add-in with a manifest configured to support shared folders, i.e.

```
<SupportsSharedFolders>true</SupportsSharedFolders>
```

The add-in has been running flawlessly, for many months, on a number of machines that meet the minimum requirement set of 1.8 for shared folder support. Since 22-Apr-2020 it has returned the following error when selecting an email in a shared email inbox:

```
Status Code: 404
ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId - Item Id doesn't belong to the current mailbox
```

The REST API call that returns this error is:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/<RestID>/
```

Where `<RestID>` is created from:  `Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId, Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0)`

Has an API change been documented anywhere?

Do we need to modify our code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a recent change. The REST URL should be constructed based on the SharedProperties descrbied here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.sharedproperties?view=outlook-js-1.8 Note that the SharedProperties API is only available for shared items.

Comment: Thanks for this information. How do we determine if a mailbox item is in a shared mailbox?

Comment: Office.context.mailbox.item.getSharedPropertiesAsync is defined only for an item in a shared scenario. So, if (Office.context.mailbox.item.getSharedPropertiesAsync) { // shared item … } else { // not shared ... }. 2 things to confirm: 1. are you seeing the error in Read mode for the addin (since you are using Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId)? 2. Are you seeing this in Outlook for Windows, Mac or Online?

Comment: We are seeing ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId in Read mode on Outlook for Windows, Mac AND Online. As I mentioned in my question, this started on 22-Apr-2020 with no code changes at our end. Following your answer, we now have a new working method that will read a mail item from a shared mailbox using Office.context.mailbox.item.getSharedPropertiesAsync(). However, we now require some way of determining which method to execute - either the original https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/<RestID>/ or the getSharedPropertiesAsync() route.

Comment: You suggest that we check with if (Office.context.mailbox.item.getSharedPropertiesAsync), however the documentation clearly states "This method is not supported in Outlook on Mac, iOS, or Android", so am I correct in thinking that if a Mac user attempts to run our add-in with a mail item in a shared mailbox, then this if statement will return false and our original method will execute resulting in ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId?

Comment: We are actively working towards enabling this feature on Outlook for Mac, but on other clients, which doesn't support 1.8 the add-in will not even be available on a shared item.