# Outlook Add-in ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId - Item Id doesn't belong to the current mailbox when downloading attachments

Tags: outlook, office-js, add-in, outlook-web-addins

We have an office add-in where we get contents of email, its attachments and send them to our SaaS application to be filed/saved. This works as expected until we try to retrieve attachments of an email from shard mailbox.

This has been working fine, but recently users have reported that they cannot. On testing, we found that, we can get the contents of the shared email (Body) but not the attachments (we can see that the add-in shows the email body and lists all attachments) but there is no attachment content, so when saved in the application, the email is saved with empty files.

The error we get when downloading attachment is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId",
        "message": "Item Id doesn't belong to the current mailbox."
    }
}
```

API Call:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/<restId>/attachments/<attachmentId>/?$expand=Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemAttachment/Item($expand=Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message/attachments
```

I've already had a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597663/outlook-add-in-rest-api-in-shared-inbox-fails-errorinvalidmailboxitemid-item) but hasn't helped much. I am testing this on mac but will test on windows.

Any more info regarding this would be helpful.

Comment: What client are you testing this on? Mac Outlook or the online web client? The REST URL in your post won't work for shared items. You should construct it using the instructions from the documentation for SharedProperties : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.sharedproperties?view=outlook-js-1.8

Comment: I am testing it on both, will update the REST URL and test again. But just wondering, what has changed recently that has made the current REST fail? As, it was working before. Cheers

Comment: It should work for the online web client. For Mac Outlook, it is currently not supported.

Comment: If it was working before, then I believe it was working on items that were not in a shared mailbox. Items that are not in a shared mailbox are in the user's mailbox, so using "/me/" in the REST URL will work because that refers to the user's e-mail address. For items in a shared mailbox, the REST URL will need to contain the e-mail address of the shared mailbox instead of the user's e-mail address.

Comment: Thanks, updating the REST from "/me/" to "/users/<mailboxaddress>/<operation>" works and I can now retrieve the attachments, but now I can't see how I can check if to use "/me/" or "/users/", there is no property on "Office.context.mailbox" that tells that the current items is from a shared mailbox or probably because I am on "Mac" I can't see the "SharedProperties"

Comment: See the answer posted below. The last link points to sample code that is doing what you need. If an item is from a shared mailbox, it will have the `getSharedPropertiesAsync` method. If it is not from a shared mailbox, the method will be nonexistent.

Answer (score 2):

For items from a Shared Mailbox, use the `Shared Properties` interface to construct the REST URL, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.sharedproperties?view=outlook-js-1.8). To determine whether to use `Shared Properties` or not, check for [requirement set 1.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.8/outlook-requirement-set-1.8) as well as the existence of the `getSharedPropertiesAsync` method. For sample code on how to check for a requirement set, see this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets).For sample code on how to check for and use the `Shared Properties` interface, see this [other documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-1.8#getsharedpropertiesasync-options--callback-).

Comment: Thanks, that is all sorted. As per the docs, it's not supported on Mac, so is there any other way to handle this on mac? or we will just have to show a small message on Outlook for mac, to say "Shared mailbox is currently not supported".

Comment: Yes, this API getSharedProperties is not yet supported on Outlook Mac. We will be adding support for this soon.

Comment: Can you please confirm if it's old Outlook UI or new Outlook UI(Phoenix UI)?

Comment: I believe it's the new UI. Would it be the same for Outlook on mac?

Comment: Yes, API spec would be same for Outlook mac also in future. But Currently getSharedProperties is not yet supported on Outlook Mac.